# How do you exactly earn bitcoins... ive been confused frankly

Tags: bitcoind

I get the concept of it just dont know how.

Answer (score 0):

You acquire Bitcoin one of two ways. You either buy it or earn it.

If you want to earn Bitcoin you are looking for Bitcoin mining unless your boss wants to pay your salary in BTC.

There are also websites where you can earn Bitcoin for completing tasks.

Comment: [Earn.com](https://earn.com/maxvernon/referral/?a=rag8puqchy13hk2w) offers an example of how to earn bitcoin without buying it.

Comment: Actually so does [coinworker.com](http://coinworker.com). I should update my answer.